# Magento 2 from developer to production mode e-mail / mail

Tags: magento2, order-email, production-mode

Magento 2.1.2
If i change from developer to production mode the order email layout is little confused.
Can help me somebody to fix that?

developer mode:
[image: developer mode]

production mode:
[image: production mode]

Comment: If u want to override then `magento\app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Theme Name>\Magento_Sales\email\order_new.html`

Comment: yes i know that. The Problem is other, in developer mode the layout is perfect if i change to production the layout is not correct. Do you know why or any help?

Comment: Hey @FloWord, I'm facing almost the same problem currently, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hey @ Mo Friedrich, no - the problem is still here.

Comment: @MoFriedrich do you found any solution?

Comment: Hey @FloWord nope, sorry... In the end, I just used some flexbox CSS to move the blocks around. No way I could bill my client several days for debugging Magento ;) Sorry.